# Do regex search on int column efficiently?

Tags: sql, sql-like, sql-optimization

Suppose there is an index on integer column `id`,

How do I efficiently find those records whose `id` matches `%789%`?

`id LIKE '%789%'` won't be able to use the index and will have performance issue.

Is there a trick to do the job efficiently?

Comment: I suspect that you're asking the wrong question. I expect that there is a neater and more efficient way of achieving what it appears you're trying to do. At a completely basic level, you could have a table with only one column, containing all integers than conform to your specification. Just using this table in joins will strip out rows you don't want, much more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a computed column like convert(varchar(20), int_column) and place an index on that.  Whenever you want to use the LIKE operator against the int_column, you would do it against the computed column instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is really packed together (and not something like %4%5%6%) you might consider expanding the pattern into the corresponding integer comparisons. It would really explode your code, but should speed the actual search up considerably.

Try:

```
mod( id, 1000 ) = 789 or
(7890 <= mod( id, 10000 ) and mod( id, 10000 ) < 7900) or 
(78900 <= mod( id, 100000 ) and mod( id, 100000 ) < 79000) or 
(789000 <= mod( id, 1000000 ) and mod( id, 1000000 ) < 790000) or 
 ...
(789000000 <= mod( id, 1000000000 ) and mod( id, 1000000000 ) < 790000000
```

Obviously, if you know the range of your key is bounded you can reduce the number of comparisons.

Comment: Is this really optimized? I think the sql server still has to iterate over **all** records to do all the comparation.

Comment: The OP said he has an index on the integer column. Doing a bunch of integer compares on an integer index should be pretty quick.

Comment: Is there a way to further limit the number of rows scanned? As `explain` shows this kind of sql will still scan all rows.

Comment: Do you know anything else about the integer values in the column? It is within a certain range, or always an odd number or anything?

Comment: It's auto_increment PK, from 1 to MAX.

Comment: I'd expect an index scan, but not a table scan. Is `explain` predicting a table scan?

Comment: It's an index scan, but I think the range can still be further limited

Comment: You know that id's a sequential PK, so it's fully packed (unless you delete a lot) and each value appears exactly one time. What other limitations can you place on the range?

Comment: Suppose that I'm to search `789` against prefix or suffix,the range can be limited by `1000` times or so.Although `%789%` is more general than that, there should also be a way to limit the range,but the math is quite difficult...

Comment: Although this column is indexed, I suspect that by modding the id before using it in a comparison will prevent that index being used.

Comment: Good suggestion. Although it seems like an invariant f(x) should be something that could use the key, it's worth actually asking the database if it is that smart. :)